# MacBook Pro reboot twice every time I wake it up from sleep mode

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

I'm wondering if I need to migrate to Linux to have a functioning OS..

Anyway, my problem is present from Mavericks till El Capitan and is about rebooting twice every time I wake my MacBook Pro from sleep (open lid or hit a key).

Can you help me understanding the problem?

This is the report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       29807659-5F96-582D-7BB6-24F98CA45916

Fri Jan 15 14:20:39 2016

*** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802cc17cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802cc001d1, type 14=page fault, registers: CR0:
0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000100, CR3: 0x000000002fb3d000,
CR4: 0x00000000000626e0 RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX:
0xffffff803b32f200, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff816e08b790, RBP: 0xffffff816e08b810, RSI:
0x000000000001da01, RDI: 0x000000000001da90 R8:  0xffffff816e08ba40,
R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff8045d11000, R11:
0x0000003200d74000 R12: 0x0000000116768096, R13: 0xffffff803b32f200,
R14: 0x00000000000000c8, R15: 0x0000000000000040 RFL:
0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff802cc001d1, CS:  0x0000000000000008,
SS:  0x0000000000000010 Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000100, Error code:
0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff816e08b440 :
0xffffff802cb2bda1  0xffffff816e08b4c0 : 0xffffff802cc17cc2 
0xffffff816e08b680 : 0xffffff802cc34b73  0xffffff816e08b6a0 :
0xffffff802cc001d1  0xffffff816e08b810 : 0xffffff802cbc71c0 
0xffffff816e08bbc0 : 0xffffff802cffe203  0xffffff816e08bc00 :
0xffffff802cd387bb  0xffffff816e08bc90 : 0xffffff802cd2849c 
0xffffff816e08bce0 : 0xffffff7fae95246f  0xffffff816e08bd30 :
0xffffff7fad24b21d  0xffffff816e08bd80 : 0xffffff7fadf82cd0 
0xffffff816e08bde0 : 0xffffff7fadf8b2e6  0xffffff816e08be20 :
0xffffff7fadf51b8c  0xffffff816e08be50 : 0xffffff7faf334774 
0xffffff816e08be80 : 0xffffff7faf333aab  0xffffff816e08bed0 :
0xffffff7faf3330f6  0xffffff816e08bf20 : 0xffffff7faf3359a9 
0xffffff816e08bf40 : 0xffffff802d0d3bad  0xffffff816e08bf80 :
0xffffff802d0d3ca6  0xffffff816e08bfb0 : 0xffffff802cc125b7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.0)[76E50D45-C97B-3ED1-97C5-94E6E0EB4514]@0xffffff7fad247000->0xffffff7fad26cfff
         com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.7.5)[DAF0353B-16D5-385A-A0F3-FD5CF3BA07F2]@0xffffff7fadf4e000->0xffffff7fadf63fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort(3.1.2)[C9770628-7EFF-382E-AA63-4514C1001E50]@0xffffff7faf32b000->0xffffff7faf345fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.7.5)[DAF0353B-16D5-385A-A0F3-FD5CF3BA07F2]@0xffffff7fadf4e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7fad324000
         com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage(2.7.1)[64B4AB40-D377-3647-9F74-F8CE2DA94FA1]@0xffffff7fadf81000->0xffffff7fadf98fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.7.5)[DAF0353B-16D5-385A-A0F3-FD5CF3BA07F2]@0xffffff7fadf4e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.0)[76E50D45-C97B-3ED1-97C5-94E6E0EB4514]@0xffffff7fad247000
         com.apple.driver.CoreStorage(471.20.7)[26C5000D-7133-3A9F-A70D-FC3B2A57B72B]@0xffffff7fae905000->0xffffff7fae9e2fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.0)[76E50D45-C97B-3ED1-97C5-94E6E0EB4514]@0xffffff7fad247000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version: 14D136

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT
2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D Kernel slide:    
0x000000002c800000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff802ca00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802c900000 System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)
```

Comment: Can you please put the report in a code block?

Comment: If the issue has been present through several major OS X versions and none of the upgrades have been clean installs then I'd backup the system with Time Machine. Then make a USB Installer for the OS X version you want to run. Then boot from it, wipe the HDD and install OS X.  Test drive it for a while without restoring anything from Time Machine or installing any additional software. If the issues persists then the MBP has a hardware problem.  You might even want to run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) before doing anything. Run the full test not just the quick.

Comment: @user3439894 Apple Hardware Test ran with "everything ok". I installed Yosemite from scratch and the annoying issue is still present. Maybe I've an hardware issue anyway. Can it be a faulty memory stick?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that in the Related here on the right there are plenty questions about similar issues (restarting frequently, kernel panic, ...). It might be a compatibility issue between old hardware (2011) and new software.

Comment: I know you didn't mention any video issues however, under the circumstances my gut says it's a hardware issue and possibly one that the AHT isn't checking. Have a look at [MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) as one of the issues listed is: Computer restarts unexpectedly

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight, let you know asap

Comment: @user3439894 my model is not in the list: MacBook Pro (13-inch Early 2011)